# Comprobar hilo dormido desde otro hilo

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo un problemilla con los hilos de java. El tema es que tengo un hilo que se ejecuta cada 10 minutos, pero que tarda en ejecutarse unas veces X tiempo, y otras veces Y, por decirlo así. Pueden ser 5 segundos,o 7 o 10, no se sabe. El tema es que necesito que el otro hilo se ejecute después de que se ejecute el primero. Había pensado en hacer un `if(hilo.isInterrupted())` desde el hilo 2, pero no me deja. ¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?
Aclarar que es una aplicación web y ambos hilos los inicio desde el `superinit` desde el controlador inicial de mi proyecto. También había pensado en que un hilo llame a otro, pero no sé muy bien como hacer para que se ejecute primero el hilo 1, y después el hilo2.

```
package Hilos;

import BD.*;
import Clases.*;
import Hilos.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class HiloPartidos extends Thread {

SQLBD baseDatos = new SQLBD();
String idPartidoBD;
String idPartido;
String round;
String local;
String visitante;
String idLiga;
String equipo1;
String equipo2;
String localAbbr;
String visitanteAbbr;
String nombreCompeticion;
String fecha;
String resultado;
String ganador;
String estado;
String vFecha;
Thread hiloApuestas = new HiloPartidos();

@Override
public void run() {

    while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            //URL url = new URL("http://apiclient.resultados-futbol.com/scripts/api/api.php?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxtz=Europe/Madrid&format=xml&req=matchs&league=1&round=38&order=twin&twolegged=1&year=2017");
            //URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            //InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            File xmlFile = new File( "/archivo.xml" );
            DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            //Document doc = (Document) db.parse(in);
            Document doc = (Document) db.parse(xmlFile);
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("match");
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    idPartido = eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //idPartido=idPartido.substring(2);
                    round = eElement.getElementsByTagName("round").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //round=round.substring(2);
                    local = eElement.getElementsByTagName("local").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //local = local.substring(2);
                    visitante = eElement.getElementsByTagName("visitor").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //visitante = visitante.substring(2);
                    idLiga = eElement.getElementsByTagName("league_id").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //idLiga = idLiga.substring(2);
                    equipo1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team1").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //equipo1 = equipo2.substring(2);
                    equipo2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("team2").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //equipo2 = equipo2.substring(2);
                    localAbbr = eElement.getElementsByTagName("local_abbr").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //localAbbr = localAbbr.substring(2);
                    visitanteAbbr = eElement.getElementsByTagName("visitor_abbr").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //visitanteAbbr = visitanteAbbr.substring(2);
                    nombreCompeticion = eElement.getElementsByTagName("competition_name").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //nombreCompeticion = nombreCompeticion.substring(2);
                    fecha = eElement.getElementsByTagName("schedule").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //fecha = fecha.substring(2);
                    resultado = eElement.getElementsByTagName("result").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //resultado = resultado.substring(2);
                    ganador = eElement.getElementsByTagName("winner").item(0).getTextContent();
                    //ganador = ganador.substring(2);

                    idPartidoBD = baseDatos.consultarPartidosFutbol(idPartido);

                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    System.out.println(fecha);
                    Date date = sdf.parse(fecha);
                    long fechaApi = date.getTime();

                    java.util.Date vfecha = new Date();
                    long fechaActual = vfecha.getTime();

                    if(fechaActual <= fechaApi){
                        estado="pendiente";
                    }else{
                        estado = "empezado";
                    }



                    // use SimpleDateFormat to define how to PARSE the INPUT
                    if(idPartidoBD != ""){
                        baseDatos.insertPartidoFutbol(idPartido, round, local, visitante, idLiga, equipo1, equipo2, localAbbr, visitanteAbbr, nombreCompeticion, fecha, resultado, ganador, estado);
                    }else{
                        baseDatos.updatePartidoFutbol(idPartido, round, local, visitante, idLiga, equipo1, equipo2, localAbbr, visitanteAbbr, nombreCompeticion, fecha, resultado, ganador, estado, idPartidoBD);
                    }
                }
            }

            hiloApuestas.start();
            Thread.sleep(600000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}







package Hilos;

import BD.*;
import Clases.*;
import Hilos.*;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;


public class HiloApuestas extends Thread {

SQLBD baseDatos = new SQLBD();


@Override
public void run() {

    while (!this.isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            ResultSet rset = baseDatos.consultarEstadoPartidos();

            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de tu código para que la gente lo vea y pueda reproducir el problema, así te pueden ayudar mejor.

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo es con asynctask y lanzas el segundo hilo onPost Execute

Comment: Pero asynctask lo puedo usar en una aplicacion web? Solo he visto ejemplos de android. Se que en si es java, pero igual necesita alguna libreria o algo asi de android studio

Comment: Uppss perdona que he pensado directamente en Android. No sé si se puede usar en este caso, supongo que es posible pero no lo he probado. Siento que no sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sencilla (si sabes que el primer hilo está corriendo) es unir tu hilo actual a ese (método [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--)) para que así tu hilo actual se quede bloqueado hasta que termine el primero.

Una solución algo mejor en mi opinión es que utilices algún tipo de callback para despertar ([notify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--)) a tu segundo hilo desde el primero en cuanto termine. Lo malo es que esto implicaría dormir ([wait](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--)) tu segundo hilo primero, y a lo mejor no es lo que quieres.

La mejor solución en mi opinión es que tuvieras un [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) de un solo hilo para cada una de las tareas. El Executor de la segunda tarea puede estar parado y al terminar el primero hilo éste podría activar el Executor del segundo.

Una variación de la última solución sería hacer un Executor de un solo hilo y meter ambas tareas en orden. Esto garantiza que en cuanto termine la primera se ejecutará la segunda. Te recomiendo mirar los Executor de Java ya que te permiten hacer muchas tareas complicadas de concurrencia con facilidad.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor práctica en hilos para estos problemas es utilizar los métodos wait() y notiify() para bloquear y liberar los threads en el momento que sea necesario. Tendrías que poner en wait el segundo hilo y cuando el primero termine que invoque notify como ultima acción para "avisarle" al hilo 2 que terminó su ejecución y que ya debe empezar a trabajar. Todo esto se implementa usando un objeto con una variable flag que informa el estado del thread 1 (ocioso, trabajando, fin de ejecución) y que lee el thread 2 para saber si trabajar o esperar....